# Update SQL Server script multiple updates on one update?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to execute an update script in `SQL Server`.
When I execute this script I get back a weird message that I don't understand

This is the script:

```
UPDATE MYTABLE1 
SET Value1 = 0, Value2 = 0, Value3 = 0, Value4 = 0, Value5 = 0 
where Productnumber = 'myProductNumber' 
and value6 = 1 
and value7 != 0;
```

And the message I get back is:

```
(1 row affected)
(1 row affected)
0.000000
47023456

(1 row affected)
(4 rows affected)
```

So my question is why does it return that weird message number 3 and 4 ?(0.00000 and 47023456).

And why is there multiple jobs happening here? 
I only have one update statement but it's doing 4 jobs some how.

Comment: Is there a trigger on the table?

Comment: There's probably a trigger for (or instead of) update on the table.

Comment: Is the code you showed us the _only_ code in the entire script?

Comment: Thanks guys :) 
Yes there where in fact 3 triggers connected to the table :) 
Thanks alot for the help !

Answer (score 0):

I went and looked in the trigger file connected to my database and found several triggers connected to it.
So that is why i get multiple responses from my 1 update statement.
Thanks to everyone for helping me figure it out !